# Getting illegal access fault with error :The address 0xffdeb9f0 could not be accessed."

Tags: buffer-overflow

Getting illegal access fault with error `The address 0xffdeb9f0 could not be accessed.`

I am trying to execute a shellcode in buffer overflow vulnerability. I am able to put the shell code at the right place in the memory but it's not getting executed.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you making it jump to the buffer, or read a scripting language from it? Generally the stack isn't directly executable by the processor.

Comment: I am trying to jump to a buffer using `jmp esp` which contains my opcodes `83 c0 0c ff e0` to execute to jump to the shellcode.

Answer (score 1):

Stack and heap memory is not executable if DEP (data execution prevention) is enabled (default behavior on most recent OSes). You would need to disable it explicitly, remap memory as executable, or use ROP (return-oriented programming) to avoid executing data.